# Why does paste() concatenate list elements in the wrong order?

Tags: r, string, strsplit

Given the following string:

```
my.str <- "I welcome you my precious dude"
```

One splits it:

```
my.splt.str <- strsplit(my.str, " ")
```

And then concatenates:

```
paste(my.splt.str[[1]][1:2], my.splt.str[[1]][3:4], my.splt.str[[1]][5:6], sep = " ")
```

The result is:

```
[1] "I you precious"  "welcome my dude"
```

When not using the colon operator it returns the correct order:

```
paste(my.splt.str[[1]][1], my.splt.str[[1]][2], my.splt.str[[1]][3], my.splt.str[[1]][4], my.splt.str[[1]][5], my.splt.str[[1]][6], sep = " ")

[1] "I welcome you my precious dude"
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paste` is designed to work with vectors element-by-element. Say you did this:

```
names <- c('Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie')
paste('Hello', names)
```

You'd want to result to be `[1] "Hello Alice"   "Hello Bob"     "Hello Charlie"`, rather than "Hello Hello Hello Alice Bob Charlie".

To make it work like you want it to, rather than giving the different sections to `paste` as separate arguments, you could first combine them into a single vector with `c`:

```
paste(c(my.splt.str[[1]][1:2], my.splt.str[[1]][3:4], my.splt.str[[1]][5:6]), collapse = " ")
## [1] "I welcome you my precious dude"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `collapse` instead of `sep`

```
paste(my.splt.str[[1]], collapse= ' ')
```

---

If we use the first approach by OP, it is `paste`ing the corresponding elements from each of the subset

If we want to selectively `paste`, first create an object because the `[[` repeat can be avoided

```
v1 <- my.splt.str[[1]]
v1[3:4] <- toupper(v1[3:4])
paste(v1, collapse=" ")
#[1] "I welcome YOU MY precious dude"
```

---

When we have multiple arguments in `paste`, it is doing the paste on the corresponding elements of it

```
paste(v1[1:2], v1[3:4])
#[1] "I you"      "welcome my"
```

If we use `collapse`, then it would be a single string, but still the order is different because the first element of `v1[1:2]` is `paste`ed  with the first element of `v1[3:4]` and 2nd with the 2nd element

```
paste(v1[1:2], v1[3:4], collapse = ' ')
#[1] "I you welcome my"
```

It is documented in `?paste`

> paste converts its arguments (via as.character) to character strings, and concatenates them (separating them by the string given by sep). If the arguments are vectors, they are concatenated term-by-term to give a character vector result. Vector arguments are recycled as needed, with zero-length arguments being recycled to "".

---

Also, converting to uppercase can be done on a substring without splitting as well

```
sub("^(\\w+\\s+\\w+)\\s+(\\w+\\s+\\w+)", "\\1 \\U\\2", my.str, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "I welcome YOU MY precious dude"
```

Comment: I know, but what if I want to have the 3rd or 4th elements to be upper case? E.g. `paste(my.splt.str[[1]][1:2], toupper(my.splt.str[[1]][3:4]), my.splt.str[[1]][5:length(my.splt.str[[1]])], collapse = " ")`. This would return nonsense as well. I am sorry but it also doesn't answer the question.

Comment: But he explained what is happening. I didn't understand that this is what you meant by `collapse`. Also, you assigned the list element a variable which is different from what is in my question.